# Yahoo data feed url not working

Tags: yahoo-api

Has Yahoo stopped data feed service?

I was getting data using this link below until wednesday. Then stopped...

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=snbaopl1
```

Someone pointed out that URL has changed to this one below, but this doesn't work either...

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG&f=snbaopl1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com.*

It seems that Yahoo unfortunately discontinued the service.